# How do I smoothly store user input data with EditText and RadioButtons (with a color set as well)?

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I want to store the data from both the RadioButtons as well as the EditText values in the `User` attribute `registeredData`, but I don't know how to access my function in a way that allows me to grab all the data, as well as displaying a color change from the RadioButtons. Also how do I check if the input data is already in use (like email)?

I have tried splitting them into two different functions, but I can't get the data back from them into my `User` attribute `registeredData`. This is my first try at coding an app so any help is appreciated.

```
public class Registration extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText displayname, email, password, confirmpassword;
    private Button bsubmit;
    private RadioGroup rgroup;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);

        displayname = findViewById(R.id.displayname);
        email = findViewById(R.id.useremail);
        password = findViewById(R.id.password);
        confirmpassword = findViewById(R.id.confirmpassword);
        bsubmit = findViewById(R.id.bsubmit);
        rgroup = findViewById(R.id.rgroupteams);

        bsubmit.setOnClickListener(onRegister);
    }

    private View.OnClickListener onRegister = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final User registeredData;
            registeredData = new User();

            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.bsubmit:
                    String useremail = email.getText().toString();
                    String userdisplayname = displayname.getText().toString();
                    String userpassword = password.getText().toString();

                    registeredData.email = useremail;
                    registeredData.displayname = userdisplayname;
                    registeredData.password = userpassword;
                case R.id.rgroupteams:
                    RadioGroup group = findViewById(R.id.rgroupteams);
                    group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int idOfSelected) {
                            switch (idOfSelected) {
                                case R.id.rbtnmantis:
                                    bsubmit.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                                    bsubmit.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                                    registeredData.team = "Mantis";
                                    break;
                                case R.id.rbtlightbringers:
                                    bsubmit.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F4DC00"));
                                    bsubmit.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                                    registeredData.team = "LightBringers";
                                    break;
                                case R.id.rbtncryptographers:
                                    bsubmit.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#1C00AA"));
                                    bsubmit.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                                    registeredData.team = "Cryptographers";
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    registeredData.team = "";
                            }
                        }
                    });
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Right now the color change only turns on after I've have clicked the submit button because I don't know how to better set my `setOnClickListener()`, I haven't made use of any variables in the registeredData outside of this either, are they set up to be able to be accessed for some data (like displayname) to be displayed?

Comment: Your `onChangeListener` is added when the `onClickListener` triggers. You should call `rgroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener` in `onCreate`.

Comment: What do you mean by "smoothly"? Also, I think your outer `switch` is missing `break`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move `onCheckedChangeListener` outside of `onClickListener`. Also, move `registeredData` outside onClickListener. Make sure that registeredData is "globally" accessible. Then on button click and checked listener you can set data from input fields and from checkboxes to the object.

Second, with TextUtils.isEmpty(email.getText().toString()) you can get boolean if email is empty or not. This you can use for other input fields, just send text to the isEmpty method